# list and elements comparison python

Tags: python, list, comparison, subset

```
list1 = ['A','B']
list2 = ['a','c']
list3 = ['x','y','z']
list4 = [['A','b','c'],['a','x'],['Y','Z'],['d','g']]
```

I want to check if all elements of list (list1, list2, list3) is contained in any of list in another bigger list (list4).

I want the comparison to be case insensitive.

To be sure, here list1 and list2 is in list4 but not list3. How can I do it?

On the other note, How would I know if a list is collection of list.

In other words, how can I distinguish if list is a collection of list of just list of elements, if I am not the one who is defining the lists.

Answer (score 1):

First item - you want to do case-insensitive matching.  The best way to do that is to convert everything to one case (upper or lower).  So for each list, run

```
list1 = map(lambda x: x.lower(), list1)
```

That will convert your lists to lowercase.  Let's assume you've done that.

Second, for a comparison of two "simple" lists (not-nested), you can simply say

```
if set(list1) < set(list2):
```

to compare if list1 is a subset of list2.  In your example, it would be false.

Finally, if you want to check if a list is nested:

```
if ( type(list4[0]) == list) :
```

which in this case, would be true.  Then, just iterate over the elements of list4 and do the set comparison above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lower()` to make all elements of all lists to lowercase to achieve case-insensitivity.

```
def make_case_insensitive(lst):
    return [i.lower() for i in lst]
```

For example,

```
list1=make_case_insensitive(list1)
```

As, biggerlist is slightly different (contains list as element), you have to change the function slightly.

```
def make_bigger_list_caseinsensitive(bigger_list):
    return [[i.lower() for i in element] for element in bigger_list]

list4=make_bigger_list_caseinsensitive(list4)
```

Check if any element of the biggerlist is the superset of smaller set. Print **Is in bigger list** if condition satisfied, print **not in biggger list** otherwise. Make `set` from the `list` first.

```
print "Is in bigger list" if any(set(element).issuperset(set(list1)) for element in list4) else "not in biggger list"
```

To write it with slightly more readability, do:

```
if any(set(element).issuperset(set(list1)) for element in list4):
    print "Is in bigger list"
else:
    print "not in biggger list"
```

Finally,to check if nested list exists in biggerlist:

```
print any(type(element)==list for element in list4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) is a good way.

```
list1 = ['A','B']
list2 = ['a','c']
list3 = ['x','y','z']
list4 = [['A','b','c'],['a','x'],['Y','Z'],['d','g']]

set1 = set(map(lambda s: s.lower(), list1))
set2 = set(map(lambda s: s.lower(), list2))
set3 = set(map(lambda s: s.lower(), list3))
set4 = map(lambda l: set(map(lambda s: s.lower(), l)), list4)

print(set1) # set(['a', 'b'])
print(set2) # set(['a', 'c'])
print(set3) # set(['y', 'x', 'z'])
print(set4) # [set(['a', 'c', 'b']), set(['a', 'x']), set(['y', 'z']), set(['d', 'g'])]

lor = lambda x, y: x or y

reduce(lor, map(lambda s: set1.issubset(s), set4)) # True
reduce(lor, map(lambda s: set2.issubset(s), set4)) # True
reduce(lor, map(lambda s: set3.issubset(s), set4)) # False
```

- To do a case-insensitive string comparison, covert both strings to lowercase or uppercase.
- To test all elements in `list1` are contained in `list4`, use `set.issubset`.